# Can Windows private namespaces isolate processes based on integrity level?

Tags: windows, security, namespaces

I want to restrict a Windows private namespace (the ones created by Win32’s CreatePrivateNamespace) to a particular integrity level, so that only the current user at the current integrity level (or, if that’s not possible, the current or higher one) can create objects in this namespace.

Comment: I clarified my question. It is the latter. So after adjusting the mandatory token to include SE_GROUP_ENABLED (not sure yet how to do that but I will look), I call AddSIDToBoundaryDescriptor with the owner SID as well as the mandatory SID? I assume I can only add the mandatory SID if it is the one I have, not a lower or higher level one.

Comment: After some reading, is setting SE_GROUP_ENABLED on the mandatory label token something a regular user can do to herself? Sounds like privilege escalation. This is part of a shipping product, so I cannot have the Administrator do it.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 offers AddIntegrityLabelToBoundaryDescriptor, which is what I was looking for. Windows Vista probably could not do it properly, otherwise Microsoft would not have added the function.